# WebApi: mapping parameter to header value

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I've done a few searches but haven't seem to find anything...

Using WebApi, I would like to map an input parameter to a header value:  e.g.

E.g. in controller:

```
public User GetUser(int id){
   ...
   return user;
}
```

I want WebApi to map the id parameter to a header value (e.g. X-Auth: 1234)... rather than an URL parameter.

Is this supported?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I don't think this is supported out of the box, like for example with the [FromBody] attribute. 
It seems you should be able to achieve this functionality by using Model Binders, as described [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api). In the model binder you have access to the request and its headers, so you should be able to read the header and set its value to the bindingContext.Model property.

Edit: Reading the article further, it seems a custom HttpParameterBinding and a ParameterBindingAttribute is a more appropriate solution, or at least I would go this way. You could implement a generic [FromHeader] attribute, which does the job. I am also fighting the same problem, so I will post my solution once I have it in place.

Edit 2: Here is my implementation:

```
public class FromHeaderBinding : HttpParameterBinding
{
    private string name;

    public FromHeaderBinding(HttpParameterDescriptor parameter, string headerName) 
        : base(parameter)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(headerName))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("headerName");
        }

        this.name = headerName;
    }

    public override Task ExecuteBindingAsync(ModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider, HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> values;
        if (actionContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValues(this.name, out values))
        {
            actionContext.ActionArguments[this.Descriptor.ParameterName] = values.FirstOrDefault();
        }

        var taskSource = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
        taskSource.SetResult(null);
        return taskSource.Task;
    }
}

public abstract class FromHeaderAttribute : ParameterBindingAttribute
{
    private string name;

    public FromHeaderAttribute(string headerName)
    {
        this.name = headerName;
    }

    public override HttpParameterBinding GetBinding(HttpParameterDescriptor parameter)
    {
        return new FromHeaderBinding(parameter, this.name);
    }
}

public class MyHeaderAttribute : FromHeaderAttribute
{
    public MyHeaderAttribute()
        : base("MyHeaderName")
    {
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult GetItem([MyHeader] string headerValue)
{
    ...
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: Would [FromHeader("MyHeader")] also work with your Code?

Comment: Yes, but that didn't exist in 2013, I'm guessing. @ChristianKuetbach

Answer (score 24):

WebApi on DotNet Core has a has some additional attributes for extracting data from the request. **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.FromHeaderAttribute** will read from the request head.

```
public ActionResult ReadFromHeader([FromHeader(Name = "your-header-property-name")] string data){
   //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Thank you filipov for the answer..  I took your code and modified it a bit to suit my needs. I am posting my changes here in case anyone can make use of this.

I made 2 changes.

1. I liked the idea of the FromHeaderAttribute, but without subclassing. I made this class public, and require the user to set the param name.
2. I needed to support other data types besides string. So I attempt to convert the string value to the descriptor's parameterType.

Use it like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public void DeleteWidget(long widgetId, [FromHeader("widgetVersion")] int version)
{
    ... 
}
```

And this is my FromHeaderBinding

```
public class FromHeaderBinding : HttpParameterBinding
{
    private readonly string _name;

    public FromHeaderBinding(HttpParameterDescriptor parameter, string headerName)
        : base(parameter)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(headerName)) throw new ArgumentNullException("headerName");
        _name = headerName;
    }

    public override Task ExecuteBindingAsync(ModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider, HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> values;
        if (actionContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValues(_name, out values))
        {
            var tempVal = values.FirstOrDefault();
            if (tempVal != null)
            {
                var actionValue = Convert.ChangeType(tempVal, Descriptor.ParameterType);
                actionContext.ActionArguments[Descriptor.ParameterName] = actionValue;
            }
        }

        var taskSource = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
        taskSource.SetResult(null);
        return taskSource.Task;
    }
}
```