# Swashbuckle custom header per method

Tags: c#, http-headers, swagger, swashbuckle

If my method in my API looks for some custom property that is in the header, ie `HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers.Exists("foobar")`, is there a way for me to decorate that method so that Swashbuckle can generate that header for Swagger to test the method with?

I've had good success with decorating with `SwaggerResponse` for my methods, to specify return types/codes, but not specifying headers.

I've also been able to add HTTP headers to EVERY request by the way of injecting custom JavaScript:

```
(function () {
    $(function () {
        $('#input_apiKey').off();
        $('#input_apiKey').on('change', function () {
            var key = this.value;
            if (key && key.trim() !== '') {
                swaggerUi.api.clientAuthorizations.add("key", new SwaggerClient.ApiKeyAuthorization("Authorization", key, "header"));
            }
        });
    });
})();
```

and in `SwaggerConfig.cs`:

```
c.InjectJavaScript(thisAssembly, "Api.CustomContent.jwt-auth.js");
```

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20618900/webapi-mapping-parameter-to-header-value It probably answers your question.

Comment: @venerik It almost does, I'll write a solution and answer it myself in a bit.